# bootstrap table with clickable row event and how to exclude a column or cell

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I have this function for row click:

```
$("#table").on("click-row.bs.table", function (row, $el, field) {
  if (column != 4) {

  }
});
```

and what condition I could add which would exclude a specific column or cells in the column? I can't find under `row, $el or field` things which would identify for ex. a cell index.

Answer (score 6):

I've finally found the answer for my question (if somebody would need it, it's more simple then I thought):

```
 $("#table").on("click-cell.bs.table", function (field, value, row, $el) {
    if (value !="column_name"){
      //the code
    }
 });
```

here is an example (with the access to all the values of the clicked row): [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fjykowtL/25/)

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's best to listen for the entire row-clicks with `click-row.bs.table`.
Then `columns` is a simple JSON with the keys you've provided from the `t` variable.

```
 $("#summaryTable").on("click-row.bs.table", function (editable, columns, row) {
   console.log("columns:", columns);

   // You can either collect the data one by one
   var params = {
         id: columns.id,
         type: columns.type,
       };
   console.log("Params:", params);

   // OR, you can remove the one that you don't want
   delete columns.name;
   console.log("columns:", columns);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

```
$("table").on("click", "tr td", function () {
   var col = $(this).index();
   if(col != 2){
     console.log("OK");
   }        
});
```

note that `$.index()` value is **0 based** (so for column 4 you should use index 3)

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/fjykowtL/24/)

Comment: I can't make it work, have a look here [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fjykowtL/18/).

Comment: look here: https://jsfiddle.net/fjykowtL/21/ --- i assumed columns were `td` elements but you have `th` instead. also, use `this` instead of `row`

Comment: well, its still not what I need because if you add this if condition let say: `index !=2` it shouldn't fire console.log at all, but it still fires for other indexes with the click.

Comment: `if(index != 2){ console.log(index); }` means that will print out index 0 and 1 (not 2). that's the meaning of that condition. What are you trying to do?

Comment: what I need is: if I click any cell in a row I want to execute a code (like console.log) but except one cell in a column let say the last one (index=2) then I don't want to execute any code at all, just pass with no action.

Comment: here is the example of console.log [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fjykowtL/22/) I don't want to fire this code when clicking the last column. How to do this? :) I hope you know what I mean now :)

Comment: ahh ok! so you need to attach click event on cell, not the full row. see https://jsfiddle.net/fjykowtL/23/

Comment: thank you for your answer, it's almost there, but I lost the access to the `$el` and I can't get all the values of the clicked row `console.log($el.id+"-"+$el.name+"-"+$el.type);` that's why I used the click-row event.

Answer (score 1):

If found a 5 liner solution for a clickable bootstrap row with field exceptions. In the `tr` tag may define your link:

```
<tr data-href="somelink.html">
```

`columnname` is the column you want to exclude from being clickable.

```
$('#table').on('click-cell.bs.table', function (field, value, row, $element) {
  if (value != 'columnname') {
    window.location = $element._data.href;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the index via `[...this.parentNode.children].indexOf(this)`

```js
 $("#table").on("click", ".click-cell.bs.table", function (field, value, row, $el) {
     console.log([...this.parentNode.children].indexOf(this));
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="click-cell bs table">1</td>
            <td class="click-cell bs table">22</td>
            <td class="click-cell bs table">3</td>
            <td class="click-cell bs table">4</td>
            <td class="click-cell bs table">5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="click-cell bs table">1</td>
            <td class="click-cell bs table">22</td>
            <td class="click-cell bs table">3</td>
            <td class="click-cell bs table">4</td>
            <td class="click-cell bs table">5</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("#summaryTable tbody tr td").click(function(){
    var col = ($(this).index());

    if(col == 2 || col == 1)
    {
        alert("do nothing");
    }
        alert("do something");
    }
  });
```

This will happen when the first column is clicked but not the second or third.

Tables are much like arrays, 0 is the first so if we had 3 columns in a table you would have column 0,1,2.

You can add more values into if statement

Hope this helps

Comment: this will work only if you click these cells, not the entire row (like the OP)

Comment: this isn't what I'm looking for if check here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fjykowtL/19/) you will see it only works for first row not in the column.